# Is the verb ‘recollect’ used in American English? How is it different from ‘remember’?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, differences, synonyms, transatlantic-differences

I (American English) am a plaintiff in a lawsuit taking place in Malta (UK English) that involves some British people as well as some Americans.

When cross-examining a British person, many of his replies were:

> I do not recollect.

I assumed that he meant *I do not remember*.

To my ears, it sounds like it's linked to memory collection, etc. But I found the expression rather odd, and I've never heard it before.

- Is *recollect* sometimes used in American English as well?
- Does it have any differences with *remember*?

Can anyone shine a light on the use of that verb?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137529/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-is-the-verb-recollect-used-in-american-englis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assumed that he meant I do not remember.

Maybe, but what he said is *I can not remember*. *Recollect* sets the bar a tiny bit higher than *remember*. *Remember* admits a passive meaning that *recollect* does not. *Recollect* means you tried to remember. The distinction appears in several legal definitions. [*Black's* definition of *mislay*](https://thelawdictionary.org/mislay/) is "To deposit in a place not afterwards recollected; to lose anything by forgetfulness of the place where it was laid."

Comment: How about providing a reference for the meaning of *recollect* you're using?  I looked in some dictionaries and found something different: that *recollect* = *remember*.

Comment: Another (grammatical) difference is that "recollect" does not usually take an infinitive dependent. E.g., I can "remember" to turn off the stove, but I would not normally "recollect" to turn off the stove.

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfectly normal word that any educated native speaker with a normal vocabulary is going to know without thinking — no matter their country of origin.

Per [this ngram of the last fifty years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recollect%3Aeng_2019%2Crecollect%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Crecollect%3Aeng_us_2019%2Crecollect%3A+eng_fiction_2019&year_start=1969&year_end=2019&corpus=27&smoothing=1&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecollect%3Aeng_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecollect%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecollect%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecollect%3A%20eng_fiction_2019%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crecollect%3Aeng_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecollect%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecollect%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecollect%3A%20eng_fiction_2019%3B%2Cc0), it is even more common in fiction than in nonfiction, and has no notable British bias.

[image: ngram of recollect]

Comment: Are we allowed to say educated speaker? Ha ha. Some time ago, I referred to uneducated speakers and the PC hand from the sky tried to strike me down.

Comment: @Lambie - I guess when you pass 100k and have put in one-quarter as much service here at tchrist, you may be given more leeway.  But don't forget to flag when you detect a problematic post or comment.

Comment: @aparente001 Personally, I see no problem with saying that. After all, it is the truth. There are educated and uneducated people. The idea is to help everyone get an education and not repress the fact some are not.

Answer (score 5):

*Remember* and *recollect* are actually not as closely comparable as *recollect* and *recall*, so it seems reasonable to consider how different reference works deal with each of these three terms.

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) compares *remember*, *recollect*, and *recall* as follows:

> **Remember, recollect, recall, remind, reminisce, bethink, mind** are not as a group synonymous terms, although they all carry as their basic meaning to put one (often oneself) in mind of something. **Remember**, except in a few idiomatic expressions such as "*remember* me to him" (i.e., put me and my regard for him in his mind) and in older literary use (as "*Remembering* them the truth of what they themselves know"—*Milton*), now implies a putting oneself in mind of something. The term in current use carries so strong an implication of keeping in one's memory that it often implies no conscious effort or willing; as, he *remembers* every detail of that occurrence as though it happened yesterday; "The average reader of the newspaper or short story reads to forget, not to *remember*" (*C. W. Eliot*); "Years—so many of them that no one *remembered* the exact number" (*R. Bradford*). **Recollect** (which is distinguished from *re-collect* only in pronunciation and in bearing a more specific significance) etymologically presupposes a scattering and implies a gathering of that which has been scattered: it is distinguished from *remember* in presupposing a letting go from rather than a retaining in one's memory and therefore implies a bringing back, sometimes with effort, to one's own mind that which has not been in it for an appreciable period of time; as, "She tried to *recollect* some instance of goodness, some distinguished trait of integrity or benevolence, that might rescue him from the attacks of Mr. Darcy" (*Austen*); "Beasts and babies *remember*, that is, recognize: man alone *recollects* (*Coleridge*); ... **Recall** often comes close to *recollect* in implying volition or an effort to bring back what has been forgotten, but it differs from *recollect* in suggesting a summons rather than a process of process of thought; often, also, it connotes a telling of that which is brought back; as, "Let me *recall* a case within my own recent experience" (*Mencken*); ...

S. I. Hayakawa, *Modern Guide to Synonyms and Related Words* (1968) has this:

> **remember, memorize, recall, recollect, remind, reminisce, retain review** These words refer to the act of summoning up the past, to its spontaneous cropping up in the mind, or to the fixing of present data in the memory for future reference. **Remember** can refer generally to any mental glance at the past, voluntary or involuntary: He caught himself *remembering* how his first wife would have cooked  the same meal; struggling to *remember* where he had been at the time the murder took place. But often the word specifically suggests the staying power of a vivid past event or circumstance: I can still *remember* every detail in my old dormitory room at college. **Recall** is more formal than remember and more often indicates a voluntary summoning up of the past, whether silently for oneself or verbally for others. {He *recalled* his last evening with his fiancee whenever he felt depressed; In his closing speech to the jury, the prosecutor *recalled* the mass of incriminating evidence he had developed during the trial.} But unlike *remember*, the word can refer to something in the present that resembles and therefore calls up something in the past; a view that *recalled* to him the fishing village he had stayed in during the war. ...
>
> When used interchangeably with *recall*, **recollect** can have a regional flavor: I don't rightly *recollect* when I saw her last. But the word can apply without this flavor to the act of casting one's mind back over past events in a leisurely and ruminative manner, whether silently to oneself or verbally to others. The word can suggest the active process of piecing together dimly *remembered* and half-forgotten details: He settled back with great relish and began to *recollect* those battles in the war that he had witnessed first-hand.

Adrian Room, *The Penguin Dictionary of Confusibles* (1979) addresses the relationship between *remember* and *recollect* somewhat tangentially, in an entry that focuses on how *recollect* and *recall* differ:

> **recall/recollect** (remember) To 'recall' is to remember something specifically, and usually clearly, as one 'recalls' an occasion, someone's face, or a promise made. To 'recollect' is to 'recall' with an effort, the implication being  that one has to 'collect' or 'muster' one's thoughts. The two verbs are often used indiscriminately as mock-bookish alternatives for 'remember': 'I don't recall the occasion.'

---

***Discussion***

These three reference works do not entirely agree on the particular implications of each term, but they generally support the idea that *remember* involves the least preparatory effort, whereas both *recall* and *recollect* are more strongly directed and volitional, with *recall* entailing a summoning to mind and *recollect* suggesting a gathering up in the mind from scattered or locations or fragmentary memories.

In everyday use, I doubt that most people put that much thought into their choice of *remember* versus *recollect* versus *recall*. As Adrian Room observes, most English speakers tend to use *remember* when not inclined to indulge in what he calls "mock-bookish" speech, although I have no doubt that some people habitually use *recall* or *recollect* instead of *remember* for even the most pedestrian instances of finding something in their memories.

Court testimony is, of course, a great occasion for mock-bookish formality—and in any case, the implied mental focus of "I do not *recall*" or "I do not *recollect*" may make the witness's effort to undertake a serious search of memory seem more determined and comprehensive than "I do not *remember*" would. But as for whether a typical judge or jury would pick up on that nuance, I cannot say; my suspicion is that they probably wouldn't.

Comment: +1. 1) 'bethink'? I've never bethought or beheard that word in my life. 2) "recollect can have a regional flavor" - euphemistically 'the region is 'backwoods'